# Put reg query output into a variable

Tags: .net, windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I am a bit unexperienced with CMD and hope someone here can help me.

In one old installation script of mine I now need to check if .NET 3.5 is installed, and then either install the 3.5 package or move on with the script depending on the result.

Now I have some trouble trying to check for the installed version in my Script.

I use this reg query to look for the installed version:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" | Find "3.5"
```

which outputs a single line, if 3.5 is installed, or nothing if it isn't:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5
```

Now my idea was, to create a variable and fill the value with the output seen above.

Unfortunately something like:

```
set DNFound=reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" | Find "3.5"
if not exist %DNFound%
(
 install framework
)
```

doesn't work, because the output wont get saved in the variable.

I have researched a bit and seen people go for a loop in this format to get single values from the reg query output into a variable (sample code):

```
 for /f "tokens=3" %%x in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile /v EnableFirewall') do set FWSTATUS=%%x
```

However I get a syntax error when I try to do the same, because of the `| Find "3.5"`  part in my reg query.

Comment: Because a 2nd cmd.exe instance is involved you need to escape the pipe symbol with a caret  `^|` you should also redirect error stream to nul `2^>NUL`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, i escaped the pipe symbol and got the command working. While doing this I found out that my thought process is wrong, and I do not check here if the variable exists, but if the content of the variable exists. So i will have to go another route anyway.

Comment: I just thought I'd add, that your question seems a little strange, in the fact that **v3.5** is integral with the OS from `Windows 7` which means you would only need to check for it if the OS was at least 10 years old, _(XP up to Vista/Server 2008 R2)_.

Comment: Almost all of our W10-Workstations only have .NET 4.0 and up installed.

Comment: Every version of Windows from Windows 7, _(which means every one of your Windows 10 workstations)_, already has a minimum version of `3.5` installed. Your task is irrelevant, because there is absolutely no need to install it on any of them.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149140/296373

Comment: I can say with 100% certainty that our W10 Workstations dont have 3.5 installed. For some reason we want to keep the use of 3.5 applications at minimum. Only certain workstations in the finance sector need applications that require 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `errorlevel` to determine if the string returned successfully.

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" | Find "3.5"
if errorlevel 1 install framework
```

What happens is `find` returns an errorlevel of `1` (no match) `0` match found. This way you do not require a variable to be set.

The above can be expanded into mutlple commands:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" | Find "3.5"
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Framework not found
    install framework
    echo do something else
)
```

As for the for loop issue, as already mentioned by [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) in a comment, you need to escape the pipe `^|`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" ^| Find "3.5" 2^>nul) do set "var=%%i"
echo %var%
```

Comment: Interrestingly the command `set DNFound=reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" | Find "3.5"` does **NOT** set `DNFound` and **always** returns errorlevel 1 as the command reg query is never executed (this is not bash or powershell)

Comment: As LotPings already said setting the variable here doesnt give me the results i wanted. However I dont need the variable anymore and simply removing  the "set DNFound="  gives me the result I need . Thank you both alot. If I knew how to give you guys some +Rep I would love to do it.

Comment: @LotPings.. Yeah thanks for noticing, I forgot to remove the `set` portion.. straight copy/paste fail `:)` I fixed it.

Comment: @NickHH45 yes, It was a mistake from my side as I copied your command including the set.. I fixed it now. We do not require the set, we just want the result from `find` either `errorlevel 1` or `2`

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to your question, because it may be relevant to future users, you should be able to output all of the installed versions using a method similar to this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "rk=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
Set/A "vi=ri=0"

For /F "Tokens=3*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%rk%" /F v /K') Do If "%%B"=="" (
    If Not "%%~xA"=="" (Set/A "vi+=1"
        For /F "Tokens=2*" %%C In (
            'Reg Query "%rk%\%%~nxA" /V Version 2^>Nul^|Find /V "\"'
        ) Do Set "_v!vi!=%%D"
    ) Else (Set/A "ri+=1"
        For /F "Tokens=2*" %%E In (
            'Reg Query "%rk%\%%~nxA\Full" /V Release 2^>Nul^|Find /V "\"'
        ) Do Set/A "_r!ri!=%%F"))
If %ri% Gtr 0 (Set/A "vi+=1"
    For /F "Tokens=2" %%A In ('FindStr/B "!_r%ri%!" "%~f0"'
    ) Do Set "_v%vi%=%%A")

If %vi% Gtr 0 For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set _v') Do Echo([%%B]

Pause
GoTo :EOF

Rem Later Version Table - do not remove
378389 4.5
378675 4.5.1
378758 4.5.1
379893 4.5.2
393295 4.6
393297 4.6
394254 4.6.1
394271 4.6.1
394802 4.6.2
394806 4.6.2
460798 4.7
460805 4.7
461308 4.7.1
461310 4.7.1
461808 4.7.2
461814 4.7.2
528040 4.8
528049 4.8
```

*When a new version comes out, you simply update the content at the bottom with the relevant information, such that the detection will remain up to date.*